# YOLOv4 modification

Tags: image-processing, yolo, yolov4

I try to use yolov4 for my school project to detect certain fruit seeds, however, I have tried to add in some backgorund images into the dataset, and also try increase the max_batches as well as changing the subdivisions as well. But, all of these do not show me any improve on the accuracy. Can anyone please help me?

1. Add background images into dataset
2. Change the max_batches = 5000, 6500, 7000 and 60000. (default is 6000)
3. Change the subdivisions = 32, 16, 64

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can someone that have done image processing , please tell me how should i start  in order to improve the accuracy?